# Flask routing to view functions via inheritance

Tags: python, flask

I am currently in the process of writing a Flask application that routes endpoints to a variety of "Actions." These actions all implement a parent function called "run()"

In code:

```
import abc

class Action(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @classmethod
    def authenticated(self):
        print("bypassing action authentication")
        return True

    @classmethod
    def authorized(self):
        print("bypassing action authorization")
        return True


    @classmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def execute(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("must override execute!")

    @classmethod
    def response(self, executeResult):
        return executeResult

    @classmethod
    def run(self):
        result = ""

        if self.authenticated() & self.authorized():
            result = self.execute()

        return self.response(result)
```

The intent is that all actually used actions are derived members of this Action class that bare-minimum implement an execute() function that differentiates them. Unfortunately, when I attempt to add routes for these

```
app.add_url_rule('/endone/', methods=['GET'], view_func=CoreActions.ActionOne.run)

app.add_url_rule('/endtwo/', methods=['GET'], view_func=CoreActions.ActionTwo.run)
```

I receive the following error:

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: run
```

Does anyone know a possible solution to this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The common approach of generating view functions is to use [Flask views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/views/). Subclass your `Action` class from `flask.views.View`, `dispatch_request` method is used instead of `run`:

```
import abc
from flask.views import View

class Action(View):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def authenticated(self):
        print("bypassing action authentication")
        return True

    def authorized(self):
        print("bypassing action authorization")
        return True

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def execute(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("must override execute!")

    def response(self, executeResult):
        return executeResult

    def dispatch_request(self):
        result = ""

        if self.authenticated() & self.authorized():
            result = self.execute()

        return self.response(result)
```

And you can add routes using [View.as_view()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.views.View.as_view) method which convert your class to view function:

```
app.add_url_rule(
                 '/endone/',
                 methods=['GET'],
                 view_func=CoreActions.ActionOne.as_view('endone')
                 )
```